# Перевод вопроса в "Требует уточнения"

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Хотелось бы услышать обоснования по переводу статуса [вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449817/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) в "требует уточнения". В первую очередь от людей, его совершившего: behemothus, Ivan Olshansky, Римма Михайлова, Galina Avanesova, shampar.

Answer (score 1):

Я просмотрел вопрос и не увидел веских причин для закрытия. На вопрос снова можно давать ответы.

Было бы неплохо, если бы вы уточнили его и вообще подредактировали.